# Auto fill title

Tags: forms, nodes, 8

I'm trying to auto-fill the title a content creation form in Drupal 8 with the user ID of the person creating the node, but I can't seem to get past step 1, which is having the title default to anything. I've made a module and added this code to it:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "new_content_type_node_form") {
    $form['title']['#default_value'] = 'Test12';
  }
}
```

On the creation screen I'm using `dpm` to look at the `$form` var, and it's showing that the title does have a value in #default_value, and it is Test12, but when the form renders the title field is blank.

It seems like the way to do this in Drupal 7 and earlier was `drupal_set_title()`, but I can't find the equivalent for Drupal 8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is to use the create hook.

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function mymodule_node_create(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'node_type') {
    $node->title = 'Test12';
  }
}
```

Your code, at least without also additionally checking whether the node is new, will replace the title when editing nodes as well.

Comment: This was not working for me because the client side validation was preventing the form form submitting with no value. The idea behind what I was doing was to assign a title programmatically then hide the field so the user never had to do anything.

Comment: This is set *before* the form is displayed, which will then pick up the value and display it pre-filled in the form.

Comment: Oh, I must have been thinking of another function then. I'll accept your answer as the preferred method of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by digging a little deeper into the form array:

```
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'Test12';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check also Automatic Entity Label module.
(Maybe look through the code)

With this module, you have access to the tokens.
https://www.drupal.org/files/images/auto-entity-labels.png